# Derivative notation question

Tags: self-learning

$d = \frac{(u+au)^2}{\frac{u^2}{r} + \frac{(au)^2}{s}}$

I have a basic question concerning derivatives. If I need to find the max of $d(a)$, I know I need to take derivatives... but with respect to what according to the d(a) notation? All I read that is that I need the max of d evaluated at a

Comment: It seems like $d(a)$ is just the same as $f(x)$: the name of the function is $d$ and you see $d$ as a function of the variable $a$ (with other terms being constant in the expression of $d$).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you specified "d(a)" implies that this is a function of a only, that u and r are constants.  Differentiate with respect to a.